# onChange never gets triggered in input component that is not supposed to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

Can anyone point help me to find out why `onChange` is never being executed?

Basically I'm extending ChakraUI's `Input` component to load a value from localStorage if such value exists.

The component is correctly loading the localStorage value, but if I try to set the `value` property from the `value` state, the component becomes read-only, which means it's an uncontrolled component & etc, but `defaultValue` is supposed to circumvent this. What is the matter here?

I even tried a hack using an `useEffect` hook to read localStorage and then directly update the input using classic JavaScript DOM manipulation. It correctly updates the value but still doesn't trigger `onChange`.

I also tried using `onBlur` instead to avoid any potential problems from re-renders, which wasn't being triggered as well.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import { ChangeEvent, useState, forwardRef } from 'react';
import { Input, InputProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';

interface StoredInputProps {
  name: string;
  defaultValue?: string;
  placeholder?: string ;
  autoCapitalize?: string;
}

type CombinedInputProps = StoredInputProps & InputProps;

const StoredInput= forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, CombinedInputProps>(
  ({ name, defaultValue = '', placeholder = '', autoCapitalize = 'none', ...props }, ref) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(name);
    return storedValue !== null ? storedValue : defaultValue;
  });

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log("Handle Change")
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    // Immediately update localStorage when the value changes
    localStorage.setItem(name, newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        {...props}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default StoredInput;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{...props}` destructuring at the end of the component was overwriting my own value for `onChange`. Moving it to the top declaration solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The useState doesn't change each time the storage value change.
A better idea would be to set the value of directly after you set the storage value.
This is how you would implement it:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState, forwardRef } from 'react';
import { Input, InputProps } from '@chakra-ui/react';

interface StoredInputProps {
  name: string;
  defaultValue?: string;
  placeholder?: string ;
  autoCapitalize?: string;
}

type CombinedInputProps = StoredInputProps & InputProps;

const StoredInput= forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, CombinedInputProps>(
  ({ name, defaultValue = '', placeholder = '', autoCapitalize = 'none', ...props }, ref) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(name);
    return storedValue !== null ? storedValue : defaultValue;
  });

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log("Handle Change")
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    // Immediately update localStorage when the value changes
    localStorage.setItem(name, newValue);
    //Setting the use state
    setValue(newValue)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Input
        id={name}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={value}
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        {...props}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default StoredInput;
```

Also you can use a `useEffect` but it would be a wast of time.
I hope this answer will help you